# No Configure Button after installing new module in Drupal 7.x

Tags: drupal, popup, drupal-7

I am trying to install the `Popup Message` module in our Drupal Website version 7.x.

After installation, I enabled the module in the `Module Page` and got this notification/message:

```
Popup message: Go to "Configuration -> User interface -> Popup message" and set popup message title and body
The configuration options have been saved.
The administrator role has been reset for all permissions.
```

But when I check it, there's no `Configuration` button or the `Popup Message` module is not in the `User Interface` page. I've already tried manually installing it, or the other solutions I found in the internet but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It should be under `admin/settings/popup_message` according to the project page.

However, if we inspect the actual code that handles the routing (hook_menu), the configuration page should be found here : `admin/config/user-interface/popup_message`.

cf. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/popup_message/-/blob/7.x-1.x/popup_message.module#L48